# encoding of backslash in pythons pyautogui

Tags: python, string, encoding, pyautogui

I am trying write a python script that runs an external program automatically by clicking buttons and give keyboard input (usually file paths) with pyautogui.
Now if I try use the funktion pyautogui.typewriter(filepath) it always types the backslashes as questionmarks.
This minimal example:

```
pyautogui.typewrite('\\')
```

returns simply ?

Now, if I change my keyboard layout in the system settings to english, it correctly returns \

My default layout is german, and I cant really change that because this messes up the later stages of the program due to wrong date formats.
Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally have a workaround, based on this discussion:
https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/46

I tinkered around in _pyautogui_win.py. and changed the keyboard input for '\'.
I got the virtual keycodes on my keyboard with this handy tool:
http://www.delphiforfun.org/Programs/Utilities/KeyCodes.htm#Download
and converted them to hex codes. I then changed the _keyDown function with the addition of this:

```
if key == '\\': 
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x11, 0, 0, 0) # should be left control
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x12, 0, 0, 0) # should be alt
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xDB, 0, 0, 0) # should be alt ß
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x11, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x12, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xDB, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
        return
```

Now everything works fine. I think this solution can be applied to any non-english keyboard layouts.

Comment: That's interesting. But If you're using Windows anyhow, you could just use [`win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32api__LoadKeyboardLayout_meth.html) This may be favorable for your use case over modifying  _pyautogui_win.py -- This way you can interchange formats without permanently altering anything.

Comment: I actually tried that approach as well, and was unable to find the locale codes. I've found them now (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912390(v=winembedded.11).aspx) It might indeed be favourable, because if the package has an update someday, my code is messed up

Answer (score 2):

It's not an encoding problem, per se. It has to do with how pyautogui is sending the keyboard input. It is sending a keystroke that is, at least in this case, not considering the keyboard layout (the actual method `pyautogui` uses for this is platform-specific.)

There isn't a direct solution built into `pyautogui` for specifying keyboard locale. So, I see a couple different options...

(1) You can create a function that will change your keyboard layout as needed (exactly how you do this is platform-specific) you could even carry this out using `pyautogui` commands.

(2) Instead of providing the input `\\` for backslashes, provide the input that will produce `\` on the german keyboard, instead. If necessary, you could define a function that will accept a string argument that translates problem characters in that string into the equivalent `pyautogui` command(s) that will produce the desired output on the German keyboard. From looking at a picture of a German keyboard, it actually looks like <kbd>\</kbd> and <kbd>?</kbd> are on the same key, so you probably would just need to add a modifier like <kbd>shift</kbd> (edit: here's [an example of someone doing this with a French keyboard](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/454ok0/problem_pyautogui_module_typewrite/czvu7bm) and pyautogui

(3) Consider calling files by another method other than keyboard input, if possible, such as `os.system` or `subprocess.call`

Comment: I`ll keep option 1 as a last resort option. Option 3 is out of the question because the program I am calling needs the files as strings. I am trying option 2 right now. So pyautogui.platformModule.keyboardMapping show me that the code for backslash is 1755, which is apparently the question mark. I am now supposed to remap this, but how do I find out which value is the backslash on my keyboard?

Comment: What platform are you using? You could also use alt key codes. As in, anytime you need to type a backslash, use the alt key code for backslash, which is 92.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 with python 3.5. when I remap the slash with pyautogui.platformModule.keyboardMapping["\\"]=92 pyautogui.typewrite('\\') produces no visible output.

Comment: To clarify, [using alt codes](http://www.alt-codes.net/) a method for typing characters by holding down the alt key, then entering a sequence of numbers to produce a character. This is a different method from keyboard remapping, and it uses different values entirely. So, this goes with my suggested method of making a function that will transform your desired string into a series of pyauto commands that will produce the desired output.

But Since you're on Windows, you can actually change the keyboard layout on-the-fly with relative ease using `win32api`

Answer (score 0):

The problem (I think) is that you've escaped the quote also with \'

I honestly don't know how many backslashes you will need (I've never used pyautogui but I think this is a Python problem, not a problem with the package), so try '\\' and '\\' and '\\\'. Beyond that I think you should try to look for another solution.

Comment: Adding more backslashes only gives me more questionmarks if the amount is even, and EOL error if the amount is odd. Isn't the problem in the string encoding of python? I tried to read sys.getdefaultencoding, but this is utf-8 no matter which keyboard layout I have.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem, but I am working on Linux. The solution for me was just to use the divide.

When I am typing 'cd /home/pi' the '/' never appear, the solution was:

```
if key == '/':
    pyautogui.press('divide')
```

It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

It looks hard but is actually easy what you have to do is just make a variable and type '\\' in it then just write the variable in pyautogui like this:

```
x = "\\"
pyautogui.write(x)
```

I think your problem is now solved.