# Python writing character Ä instead off " and ' answear found but not understandable to me please try to explain it

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyautogui

I'm trying to write a script that writes a script, that writes a script and so on. I've been using the pyautogui module for this. The problem is that when I try to print out the characters " , ' it writes the character Ä. This is my script so far and I'm using a swedish keyboard:

```
import pyautogui
#command + n creates a new file in python it is the same as inputting ctrl + n
pyautogui.hotkey("command","n")
pyautogui.typewrite("import pyautogui \npyautogui.hotkey('command','n')")
```

I've found a similar question with an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040370) in stackoverflow, but they say that they have "Tinkered around" to make it work. But I'm not at a level that can understand what they have done to make this work therefore my question is:

**Could someone try to explain how to make the writing work with my swedish keyboard?**

Comment: what is your Default Keyboard layout?

Comment: I’m a swedish dude so swedish qwerty keyboard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [encoding of backslash in pythons pyautogui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040370/encoding-of-backslash-in-pythons-pyautogui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are lots of [Problems](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/46) with Keyboard Layouts in pyautogui
>   (when not using the default english layout)

You could try one of the following:

1. If you are on Windows: [Load Keyboard Layout](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32api__LoadKeyboardLayout_meth.html)

> ```
> win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout
> int = LoadKeyboardLayout(KLID, Flags)
> ```

2. You can [tinker around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040370/encoding-of-backslash-in-pythons-pyautogui/36055972#36055972) within _pyautogui_win.py

> ```
>     if key == '\\':
>         ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x11, 0, 0, 0) # should be left control
>         ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x12, 0, 0, 0) # should be alt
>         ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xDB, 0, 0, 0) # should be alt ß
>         ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x11, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
>         ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x12, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
>         ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xDB, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
>         return
> ```

3. Another solution for Linux and Mac:

In Mac and Linux there is an opportunity to input unicode characters using their hex codes. There is article on wikipedia about that. I'm writing my program for Mac so I enabled Unicode Hex Input in my keyboard settings and wrote this code:

> ```
> def type_unicode(word):
>     for c in word:
>         c = '%04x' % ord(c)
>         pyautogui.keyDown('optionleft')
>         pyautogui.typewrite(c)
>         pyautogui.keyUp('optionleft')
> ```

Comment: What do you mean with tinker around?

Comment: just edited (also follow the link to a Problem which might be similar to yours).

Comment: A Windows-specific solution will probably not work on a Mac.